# xcode5 build ios arm64 static library, error when building the assembly file

Tags: ios, xcode5, arm64

I am using xcode5 building a iOS static library which support arm64 for iphone5s, but when building the assembly file, It shows the error message as below.

```
/Users/markchen/iDev/webRTC/ios/svnWebRTC/webrtcLibSource/trunk/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/complex_bit_reverse_arm.S:1:1: error: unexpected token at start of statement
@
^
/Users/markchen/iDev/webRTC/ios/svnWebRTC/webrtcLibSource/trunk/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/complex_bit_reverse_arm.S:2:1: error: unexpected token at start of statement
@ Copyright (c) 2012 The WebRTC project authors. All Rights Reserved.
^
/Users/markchen/iDev/webRTC/ios/svnWebRTC/webrtcLibSource/trunk/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/complex_bit_reverse_arm.S:3:1: error: unexpected token at start of statement
@
^
/Users/markchen/iDev/webRTC/ios/svnWebRTC/webrtcLibSource/trunk/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/complex_bit_reverse_arm.S:4:1: error: unexpected token at start of statement
@ Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license
```

Anyone came across this problem? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to build something like

http://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/media/webrtc/trunk/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/complex_bit_reverse_arm.S

?  First of all, that's armv7 assembly which an arm64 assembler will reject as invalid.  But the error you're seeing is because the `@` characters used to mark comments in this file are not recognized by the arm64 assembler for iOS.  Are you sure this file isn't supposed to be preprocessed before it is passed to an assembler?  Or maybe it was written for a different assembler.

Comment: Yes, I am building that file indeed, I set the Xcode5 build settings->Valid Architectures = armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64. The value armv6,armv7,armv7s can build successed. The file is written for armv7, I don not know how to get rid of this problem. Can u give me some guidance? Looking forward to ur reply.

Comment: The webtrc website/developers will probably be a better resource in this case.  Answering how to build their project arm64 for iOS is not a general question that outsiders can easily answer.